# Sending data from Netsuite script to PHP server

Tags: php, json, netsuite

I have an public hosted PHP server and I would like to use NetSuite's Suitescript to send data over to the PHP server. Preferably using JSON data. I plan to create a schedule script and once that script runs it should be able to send data over to my PHP server. Can this be done?

Comment: I understand I could achieve it using an Integrator tool from Suitebundle, however I would like to try this using pure Suitescript first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once, you have hosted your PHP HTTP service on web, you can send a http to your server using nlapiRequestURL(URL).

If you are not yet ready hosting on web, you can expose your localhost service on web using tunnelling service of ngrok and http to the tunnel url using nlapiRequestURL()

Comment: How can I use nlapiRequestURL to send JSON ? Any examples?

Comment: Well, you can just send a HTTP POST request with JSON body as JSON string (you can use JSON.stringify()) and set content-type application/json in the header, Please check the documentation of NetSuite help on syntax of nlapiRequestURL()

Comment: How about authentication wise? I can include the headers during the nlapiRequestURL call, how do I authenticate this in PHP?